# socket.io not working on heroku server from 2 computers

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, socket.io

My code works fine when i connect 2 users from the same pc, but when 2 users try to communicate from different pc, socket.io can't connect.

my server:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', socket => {
    const id = socket.handshake.query.id
    socket.join(id)

    socket.on('send-message', ({ conversationRec, senderName, text }) => {
         io.emit('receive-message', { conversationRec, senderName, senderId: id, text })
    })
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is on port ${PORT}`))
```

client:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const newSocket = io(
        'https://herokuapp.com/',
        { query: { id } }
    )
    setSocket(newSocket)

    return () => newSocket.close()
}, [id])
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure your app isn't at `'https://herokuapp.com/'` directly, but it's rather exposed under a dynamic subdomain, like `https://foo-bar-12345.herokuapp.com`.

Comment: you right, i cut it off for the question.